# Netstop instantly reports service stopped which is wrong

Tags: windows, service

I need to stop a service before I update my application. Netstop instantly answers that the service is stopped but in reality it isn't (I can still see the process ID).

Is there a way to check if the process is really stopped after using netstop? Or do I have to use a delay which might work in most cases?

Answer (score 1):

We have encountered this issue with one of our previous projects. Unfortunately, you are correct and windows reports the service as stopped while it is still releasing the resources. Our solution was to check the files that are being used by the process and see if they are still in use. We checked every second until the files were released.

Comment: We are currently checking for the PID. But I do not really like both solutions. Kind of sad that there is not a handy solution to this problem.

Comment: I would like to know if there is another solution for this as well. However, based on our tests, the signal is being returned after the command and the status of the service is updated. Not when actually, everything is released and available.